# Swift 3 - Auto scroll UITextView according to length of mp3

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uitextview, mp3

In my iOS app, I have inside the lyrics of mp3s that i'm playing inside a scrollable non editable textview. I want to auto scroll the textview according to the length of each mp3. How can I do it in Swift 3?

Comment: Have you tried using a `Timer`?

Comment: Use a timer and set the scroll of your UITextView based on the position of the player.

Comment: @nighttalker , can you elaborate more please?i thought about using a timer but couldn't know how to autoscroll the textview based on the current time of the song

Comment: @Sina KH, please see my previous comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is schedule a `Timer` and calculate where to scroll in the update method (the selector).

Somewhere in your class:

```
var timer = Timer()

func update() {
    // Assuming you're using an AVAudioPlayer, calculate how far along you are
    let progress = player.currentTime / player.duration

    // Get the number of characters
    let characters = textView.text.characters.count

    // Calculate where to scroll
    let location = Double(characters) * progress

    // Scroll the textView
    text.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: Int(location), length: 10))
}
```

Then, whenever you want to start the timer:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

When the song is finished, invalidate the timer.

Comment: Great answer! Just wondering, this won't sync up with the lyrics though because they won't necessarily flow at a constant rate. He might have to put make a library of timestamp markers with the lyrics or something so that the texts syncs with the sound precisely

Comment: Thanks it worked! And yeah @Antoine was right, the scrolling didn't sync with the lyrics. I didn't think that through. I don't think it would work as i imagined it. Thanks anyways

Comment: how to handle when slider value increase for seeking song? any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You could set contentOffset:

```
func autoScroll() {
    let progress = currentTime / duration
    let contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: textView.contentSize.height * progress)
    textView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: true)
}
```

And start Timer:

```
let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
```